# How to create another partition on my pc

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to create another partition in my pc, I shrink the primary partition :E and created a new logical dive :D , But when try same for the :C , I get error that I already have maximum number of partitions.

Here are screenshots to explain this

http://i62.tinypic.com/2mchjsp.png

You can see the logical drive I created earlier, If you look at it it shows another unnamed partition too, I DO NOT KNOW WHERE IT IS , Then I tried to shrink :C and create another logical drive but I get this error.

http://i62.tinypic.com/2mchjsp.png

Now my question is HOW CAN I CREATE ANOTHER PARTITION OR IF IT IS NOT POSSIBLE IS THERE ANY WAY I CAN ADD THIS SHRINKED SPACE TO :D or :E ?

I tried my self but there is no such option . I am using win7, core i5 laptop, toshiba .

Comment: You have to delete one of the paritions or convert from MBR to GPT which isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of dividing a disk into partitions. A traditional *Master Boot Record* (MBR) holds a partition table defining up to four primary partitions. A limit of four primary partitions is restrictive for large disks, so one of these primary partitions can be made into an *Extended Partition*. Multiple logical partitions may then be created inside the extended partition. This may sound a little unwieldy, and it is.